# Why js, css, lib under wwwroot folder didn't load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I made a simple ASP MVC (Net Core 3.1) , I leave it as standard, and deploy it under a subfolder of the Apache (`/var/www/html/myapps/test/v1``)

I started the kestrel without any errors, I access the page (ie. `https://example.com/myapps/test/v1`), it shows but all css, js, lib don't load properly (ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), I see they are already in the www-root folder.

```
bootstrap.min.css
site.css
bootstrap.bundle.min.js
site.js
content.bundle.js
content.js
```

what did I miss?

Have tried to access `https://example.com/myapps/test/v1)`, it shows but some css, js, lib don't load properly (ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), I see they are already in the www-root folder.

below my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            **// Have Tried this**
            app.UsePathBase("/myapps/test/v1");

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

**my kestrel**

```
 [Unit]
 Description=.NET Web Application on Linux

 [Service]
 WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/myapps/test/v1
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet 
 /var/www/html/myapps/test/v1/WebApplication4.dll
 Restart=always
 # Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
 RestartSec=10
 KillSignal=SIGINT
 SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
 User=root
 Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
 Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
```

my apache httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:443>

```
ServerName apps.example.com
ServerAlias apps.example.com
ServerAdmin info@example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location /myapps/test/v1/>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:5003/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5003/
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: Some or all? Do some files load properly from the wwwroot folder and some don't? Any pattern regarding extensions?

Comment: bootstrap.min.css, site.css, bootstrap.bundle.min.js, site.js, content.bundle.js, content.js
bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Probably your import in your pages is not from the right path

Comment: what do you mean import pages is not from the right path?. I copied all of them from the source to correct path

Comment: `Some` can't be loaded? Is it means another  css or js can be loaded normally?

Comment: @XinranShen, sorry, I meant all of css, js, lib fails to load!
this is a very simple mvc web app, I just create it from template so it's default

Comment: @FEDon, Is your path load the js/css like `"~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`?  I guess after you deploy project under a subfolder of the Apache, The path has changed. SO you can try to write absolute paths to load the file in wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

If you host your application under the subpath `/myapps/test/v1`, then you will need to configure your ASP.NET Core application so that it *knows* that. You can do that with the `UsePathBase` method at the beginning of your `Configure` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/myapps/test/v1");

    // …
```

That way, Razor will know to generate application-relative paths (e.g. `~/bootstrap.min.css`) to as relative to that configured path base. So the browser knows to look for the files at `/myapps/test/v1/bootstrap.min.css` instead of just `/bootstrap.min.css`.

---

In your Apache configuration, try to set [`ProxyPreserveHost On`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) in order to have Apache pass the real host name instead of the internal localhost address. This should allow the ASP.NET Core application to recognize that it is being hosted externally and have the `UsePathBase` configuration take an effect when generating the links within the Razor views.

Comment: I have tried that, all of js, css, lib that located in the wwwroot are not loaded

Comment: @FBDon Can you take a look at the HTML source of your page in the browser (using `Ctrl+U`) and check how the URLs to the CSS files are generated?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure, what do you mean?, if I see from browser then view page source, I saw like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" /> .. there was no "~", but if I see in the visual studio 2019 IDE, there was '~'

Comment: Yes, the `href="/lib/bootstrap/…"` means that the browser will try to look up the files from the root. But they are actually hosted at `/myapps/test/v1/lib/bootstrap/…`. Usually, setting the PathBase should work for this. So please double check whether you have configured it correctly. – If that doesn’t help, can you post how you have configured the application within Apache?

Comment: I have added kestrel and httpd.conf info above

Comment: @FBDon Try setting `ProxyPreserveHost On` within your Apache’s `<Location>` configuration.

Comment: yes, I have tried it, still the same!